# Google PageSpeed Insights - Too much compressing on images

Tags: image, optimization, compression, pagespeed

I am currently optimizing our website and I'm surprised by the Google PageSpeed Insights. For days, I've been trying to reach a good ranking and I'm concentrating on optimizing the images. But Google PageSpeed Insights says that the pictures mostly still require a compression of 90%. You can already see that the pictures have been severely compromised and have lost in quality.

The page I'm optimizing is  knorke. de

For example:
The suggestions in the analysis show that the image "Wicked-Print-Logo.jpg" can be compressed by 95%. The image has a size of 16 KB. I do not believe that it's possible to compress the file anymore, without losing image quality.

What am I doing wrong?

Why is Google so strict here?

I'm thankful for every suggestion.

Comment: What are you using to optimize the images?  Probably the best tool these days is Guetzi (https://github.com/google/guetzli/)…

Answer (score 0):

I did a test speed insight of your page, Google already helped you to much, because it offert to you the possibility to download optimized assets (images, css and js) for your website. You just have to download it and replace your images with images optimized by Google.

Note that the decision lies to you, if you think that images optimized by google are very bad  quality, you are not oblige to use them.

I also suggest you to configure the cache browser, it could help a little boost your score

Find the link just under all test notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess in the end I have to ignore Google but why google offer some images to optimize that actually doens't exist on that page. For example: 5jahre-1-uai-2100x1181.jpg. That makes no sense to me. Do you have any idea why google is listing this image?

Comment: I don't really know how it names pictures, but generally Google gives you two images a big for desktop and a small for mobile. You can ignore google for some propositions but not for all, just do all you can to have an acceptable score on test performance because Google will check it for rancking